# Expiring links to images in Facebook share?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are implementing a facebook share dialog so users can share images from their accounts. Those images are hosted on S3 and we use expiring links to ensure that normally user images are only accessible to them.

The question is, if we provide that link to the facebook js library to create the share dialog, when the user posts, does facebook make a copy (where our link expiring 2min later is fine) or does that link have to remain available for longer or forever?  If it does make a copy, is that when the user clicks the Post button?  Or earlier when the preview is show in the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web) link,

> Share articles, photos, videos and other content as a URL that points
>   to the page where your content lives.

It seems facebook don't copy over image, it just keeps a reference.